# listView and text input working weirdly in Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, layout

So this is my first experience making an app and I've only started a few months ago, I was testing out making an app and I ran into some problems, namely with the add button and the listview. For some reason every time I click "add item" it removes the time segment, but it does not remove the name/text segment, which will be as seen in the video.

Secondly, I need to enter the text 3 times (on the third it will show) before the text with the time will show, is it a problem with the layout, listview, or something else. To add to that for my phone (Huawei P20 Pro) it needs 3 times (3rd try shows it) before it shows the text and time. While on the emulator (pixel 4) it takes 2 tries (2nd try shows the text

As I said before I am very new to java and programming in general so thanks for the help.
[image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByoQ9.png)

[Layout bug on Huawei p20 pro](https://youtu.be/eS7_nYwME1Y)
**Code for add item:**

```
 private void addItem(View view) {

    //name
    EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String itemText = input.getText().toString();

    //time
    input = findViewById(R.id.editTextTime2);
    String str = input.getText().toString();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    //adds items
    if (!(itemText.equals("")) && !(str.equals(" "))) {
        itemsAdapter.add(itemText + " " + str);
        input.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter text and time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

edit: I forgot to add but there are no error messages

edit 2: I also forgot to add but I am not sure how DateFormat and formatter works, I just found it when searching how to use time text.

Answer (score 0):

```
//name
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText);
String itemText = input.getText().toString();

//time
input = findViewById(R.id.editTextTime2); //there is a mistake EditText input is assigned to 2 ids editText and editTextTime2
String str = input.getText().toString();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

use diiferent names for EditText not same

```
//name
EditText input = findViewById(R.id.editText);
String itemText = input.getText().toString();

//time
EditText input2 = findViewById(R.id.editTextTime2);
String str = input2.getText().toString();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

//adds items
    if (!(itemText.equals("")) && !(str.equals(""))) {
        itemsAdapter.add(itemText + " " + str);
        input.setText("");
        input2.setText("");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter text and time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: and a advice from me is do not use input or input2 as values use something like for name EditText it should nameEditText and for string nameString so it will not confused you

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, it worked, and now the text works well. Do you know how to fix the first problem? I think it has something to do with the layout as the number of times I have to add items differs between devices. I linked the video in my question, thanks in advance.

Comment: update your code again if possible add full code so I can test